# CollapsingToolbarLayout in combination with SwipeRefreshLayout and Recyclerview not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am struggling to get my toolbar to collapse, I have seen some other topics on stackoverflow that -seem- to be related, but modification to my code didn't help the situation.

The swiperefreshlayout still does it's job, and I can still scroll through the recyclerview-items, but my bar isn't collapsing..
Additionally : it seems that the toolbar is overlapping a part of my recyclerview now

Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:elevation="6dp"

    android:onClick="showInputDialog"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"

    />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/aandelenlijst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the complete XML file, the snippet you added doesn't mention neither RecyclerView, nor SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: Hello there, sorry but this was my first time asking a question on stackoverflow.  The question can be closed now, i found it that I was referencing a wrong namespace ...

That being said, I'd like to learn for future questions: basically I had to post my layout files for the views included too, correct?